# Testing asynchronous polling service in RxJava

Tags: unit-testing, rx-java, rx-java2

I implemented a service that polls for eyetracking events and pushes the received data using a FlowableProcessor (PublishSubject in RxJava 1.x). The whole polling runs in a different thread that can be started and stopped using the services class methods.

I wrote a test for the service, but i am not quite sure if I am doing the right thing.

My idea:

1. Subscribe to the stream provided by the stream service
2. Start the service
3. Wait for the `onComplete` event (published automatically when the service is supplied with a non-infinite data source mock)
4. Verify the results

This is my testing code:

```
StreamService service = new StreamService(mockSource);
Flowable<ETData> stream = service.getStream();

TestSubscriber<ETData> testSub = new TestSubscriber<>();
stream.subscribe(testSub);

service.start();
testSub.await();

testSub.assertNoErrors();
testSub.assertComplete();

List<ETData> received = testSub.values();

assertEquals(2, received.size());
assertEquals(mockData0, received.get(0));
assertEquals(mockData1, received.get(1));
```

Is this okay, or am i missing something?